# Can not edit/add content to sharepoint 2007 in spite of "Total Control" permissions

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Although sharepoint administrator has full control over the sites of Sharepoint 2007, he can not add or edit content.

The owners of each of the sub-sites created a log time ago that, also, have the permission "Full Control" or other privileged permissions can not edit or add data to lists and documents. This problem arose from one day to another without having reasons for that behavior.

Any indications to solve this?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, a colleague of mine discovered that the problem was due to unavailable disk space in the the Configuration Database of SharePoint (SP), the log file contained into this database (something similar to archive logs of Oracle) grew unexpectedly and was not responding correctly to SP requests.

The log files of SharePoint and Event viewer were not very clear, they were only giving messages about the consequences.

My best regards.